# Alert() does not fire from the second page of datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable returned from backend using Jquery and datatables plugin. I need to select the order number in the datatable and alert it.  The alert and console works well in the first page of the data table but does not fire anymore from the second page. I googled it but `.live()` is deprecated and the suggested answer `.on()`seems does not work.

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //url: "OrderDetail.asmx/HelloWorld",
    url: "Order.aspx/GetOrder",
    data: "{'id':'273440'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#order').append(msg.d);
        //alert(msg.d);
        console.log(msg);
        $('#orderTable').dataTable({
            // "sScrollY": "100px",

            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bDeferRender": true
            //"bPaginate": false

        });
        // Click order number to get the details
        // Problem is here 
        $('.orderNumber').on('click', function () {
            var orderNum = $(this).text();
            console.log(orderNum);
        });

    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        // Display a generic error for now.
        alert("Ajax Error!");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaEl-Din I need to select the order number in the datatable and alert it. But it wont work in the second page of data table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The onclick event that you set up only applies to elements on the page.  This is why it only works for the first page.  You should set up the onclick events whenever datatables shows new results.  This can be accomplished by moving the onclick listener to datatables' fnDrawCallback function.

```
$('#orderTable').dataTable({
    // "sScrollY": "100px",

    "autoWidth": false,
    "deferRender": true,
    //"bPaginate": false,

    "drawCallback": function() {
        $('.orderNumber').on('click', function () {
            var orderNum = $(this).text();
            console.log(orderNum);
        });
    }
});
```

see https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback